# Why my wso2 esb api return only the first property of the original json?

Tags: json, wso2

I'm using wso2 esb 4.0.3.
I used cxf to create a jaxrs api. The first resource is simple. I use SOAP-UI to issue an HTTP GET to this resource, and it returns a json string with the data I expected. Like:

- {"id":"some id", "name": "some name", "when":"some time".......}

I created an API in wso2 esb. A resource is configured to call the backend resource mentioned above. When I call this resource using SOAP-UI, I get a json string, but with only the first property of the data. Like:

- {"id":"some id"}

What is causing this problem, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Any particular reason to use ESB 4.0.3? Will you be able to try latest version and check? http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/

Comment: Adding RESTful API to an existing system which is using WSO2 ESB v4.0.3. I'd like to try the latest, but the working force wouldn't.